# Ionic-AngularJS-Whats do the flags -lcs stand for in ionic run android -lcs?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, lcs

I wanted to ask what the flags "lcs" in "ionic run android -lcs" mean?
(I had an error with the ionic framework that my app was only builded in the right way when using this flags but I don't know what they do stand for.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three letters, separately, are abbreviations for the options of:

- --livereload
- --consolelogs
- --serverlogs

[See more here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html).

Comment: Thank you, I actually didn't find this ionic documentation page before.. ;)